# not able to search a pattern in given string using Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, string, swift

For given NSstring, i need to search an ip address and display it.
Below is the sample code but don't know why it does not work.

String is

```
(SII_Bg

SII Bg

Disconnected  ( User Disconnected )  



N/A



SII_Bg_IP

SII Bg via Router

Connected    (00:19:36)

191.30.33.55 

N/A 

)
```

function searchIPString()

```
var validIpAddressRegex : String = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern : validIpAddressRegex, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)

    let abc = NSString(data: myData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let  xyz  = abc as! String

 let newString = xyz.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

            let results = regex.matchesInString(newString,

                options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, abc!.length))

                as! [NSTextCheckingResult]


            print(results)
```

1. mydata is NSData which is converting into NSString.
2. mydata contains above value.
3. replacing "\n" in the newString.

but the results value is "0 elements" even though the string has valid ip address. 
Please let me know where i'm going wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even simplify the regex a bit. Do something like this.

```
func searchIPString(string: String) -> [String]? {
    let regex = "\\d{1,3}[.]\\d{1,3}[.]\\d{1,3}[.]\\d{1,3}"
    do {
        let regularExpresion = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: .CaseInsensitive)
        let matches = regularExpresion.matchesInString(string, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))

        var matchingIPs = [String]()
        let convertedString = string as NSString
        matches.forEach { textCheckingResult in
            let range = textCheckingResult.range
            let foundIP = convertedString.substringWithRange(range) as String
            matchingIPs.append(foundIP)
        }

        return matchingIPs
    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("Regular Expression Format is Wrong: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    return []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try following pattern to search in whole string , you dont need to replace newlines

```
let pattern = "\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b"
```

code would be something like

```
let pattern = "\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b"
do {
    let string = "Your Text"
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
    let matches = regex.matchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count))
} catch {

}
```